# Manually invoke ScalaPB compiler in an SBT task

Tags: scala, sbt, protocol-buffers, scalapb

I'm using [ScalaPB](https://trueaccord.github.io/ScalaPB/) to synthesize Scala classes for converting my data to and from [Protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf/) representation. By default, [the SBT setup](https://trueaccord.github.io/ScalaPB/sbt-settings.html) hooks into `sbt compile` to generate the files under the `target` folder.

Because I expect my `.proto` files to change very infrequently, I would rather manually invoke the ScalaPB process when they do, and keep the generated files under version control. This is the same approach I use for [Slick's code generation functionality](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/code-generation.html).

I can do something like:

```
lazy val genProto = TaskKey[Unit]("gen-proto", "Generate Scala classes from a proto file")
genProto := {
  val protoSources = ...
  val outputDirectory = ...

  // ? run the same process 
}
```

But I'm not sure how to invoke the process from SBT with custom inputs and outputs.

My latest attempt:

```
ScalaPbPlugin.runProtoc in ScalaPbPlugin.protobufConfig := (args =>
  com.github.os72.protocjar.Protoc.runProtoc("-v261" +: args.toArray))

lazy val genProto = TaskKey[Unit]("gen-proto", "Generate Scala classes from a proto file")

genProto := {
  val protoSourceDirectory = sourceDirectory.value / "main" / "protobuf"
  val outputDirectory = (scalaSource in Compile).value / outputProtoDirectory
  val schemas = (protoSourceDirectory ** "*.proto").get.map(_.getAbsoluteFile)
  val includeOption = Seq(s"-I$protoSourceDirectory")
  val outputOption = Seq(s"--scala_out=${outputDirectory.absolutePath}")
  val options = schemas.map(_.absolutePath) ++ includeOption ++ outputOption
  (ScalaPbPlugin.runProtoc in ScalaPbPlugin.protobufConfig).value(options)
  (outputDirectory ** "*.scala").get.toSet
}
```

I get the following error:

```
> genProto
protoc-jar: protoc version: 261, detected platform: mac os x/x86_64
protoc-jar: executing: [/var/folders/lj/_85rbyf5525d3ktt666yjztr0000gn/T/protoc2879794465962204787.exe, /Users/alan/projects/causality/src/main/protobuf/lotEventStoreModel.proto, -I/Users/alan/projects/causality/src/main/protobuf, --scala_out=/Users/alan/projects/causality/src/main/scala/net/artsy/auction/protobuf]
protoc-gen-scala: program not found or is not executable
--scala_out: protoc-gen-scala: Plugin failed with status code 1.
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Apr 25, 2016 9:39:09 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

lazy val genProto = TaskKey[Unit]("gen-proto", "Generate Scala classes from a proto file")

genProto := {
    Seq("/path/to/scalapbc-0.5.24/bin/scalapbc",
        "src/main/protobuf/test.proto",
        "--scala_out=src/main/scala/") !
}
```

Comment: I think my problem is that I don't know what the path to `scalapbc` is

Comment: That is, the executable as installed by SBT. I'd really like to keep the workflow all within SBT, if possible, so no dependencies need to be manually installed.